# Problem using the 'paperclip' gem and Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 on a MacOs running 'Snow Leopard' v1.6.5.

I want to use the 'paperclip' gem so I included it in my Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'paperclip', "~> 2.3"
```

Then, in the Terminal I run the command:

```
sudo bundle install
```

The result is:

```
...
Using paperclip (2.3.8) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.1) 
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

that means that 'paperclip v2.3.8' is installed.

Then I restarted 'apache' from the 'System Preferences/Sharing/ panel

Using my RoR application and navigating locally in the website, I realized that something was wrong. So, going to see logs in the 'Console Messages', I found the following:

```
18/01/2011 16:50:52 org.apache.httpd[12972] [31mCould not find paperclip-2.3.8 in any of the sources[0m
```

**What means? How to resolve the problem?**

---

**UPDATE ( important ! ! ! )**

I reinstalled correctly RVM and now, running the command 'rvm', I get it to work... but 'paperclip' doesn't yet: in logs I still have the problem '`Could not find paperclip-2.3.8 in any of the sources`'.

Notice: this time I used `bundle install` instead of `sudo bundle install`!

*I discovered that running the command 'rails server' in the Terminal, my RoR3 application works great with 'paperclip' on the URL `http://0.0.0.0:3000`. It doesn't when I use the basic installation of apache from 'Snow Leopard' on the URL `http://project.local`.* **Why does it happen?!**

---

**EDIT (after a request in an answer)**

The output of `rvm info` is:

```
/usr/local/bin/rvm: line 73: /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
...
<A lot of the same line>
...
/usr/local/bin/rvm: line 73: /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/rvm: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/usr/local/bin/rvm: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

---

P.S. I: I tryed to use `gem 'paperclip', '2.3.8'` instead of `gem 'paperclip', "~> 2.3"`, but it doesn't work.

P.S. II: I am also using *MacPorts* and I have installed *Image-Magick*.

Comment: are you running system ruby or through rvm?

Comment: Might not solve your problem, but it's bad practice to add sudo to bundle install, as discussed here: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html

Comment: If you're running apache, what are you using to run rails? You may want to make sure you're restarting that server after installing paperclip

Comment: I think I am running system ruby but I am not sure because, long time ago, I installed RVM and now if I digit 'rvm' at the Terminal I get: "/usr/local/bin/rvm: line 73: /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory ...". (!!!)

Comment: I am using apache and I restarted it from the 'System Preferences/Sharing/ panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get: "/usr/local/bin/rvm: line 73: /Users//.rvm/scripts/rvm

Well, that is interesting. You should not see rvm in `/usr/local/bin`, so something is messed up. *Please add the output of `rvm info` to your question by editing it.*

Unless you have very special needs, and, if you did you'd know it because you'd be administering a host for multiple users, you should never use `sudo` with rvm or a rvm controlled gem. The mixed permissions caused by `sudo`, or by running as root as you install rvm, will cause all sorts of weird behavior.

If you have mixed/multiple rvm versions, then the first job is to clean out the rat's nest and return things to a clean/stable state.

Then, you can install a current version of rvm, and let it install your Rubies. Also, it is really important to keep rvm up to date using `rvm get head`. The author updates it several times a week, and the updates are transparent but add bug fixes and new features.

---

Edit: `rvm info` shows "bad brokage".

We need to figure out where rvm is installed, besides your `~/.rvm` path. At the command-line type:

```
locate rvm | grep -v /Users
```

In particular we're looking for any instances of the `rvm` shell script. For instance, this is a second version I have installed to help TextMate work with rvm:

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/lib/rvm
```

Notice it's just the word "`rvm`" at the end of the line.

---

EDIT: "I founded:"

Ok, that's good news. RVM is designed to work from one directory. You can run a couple commands to clean up the `/usr/local` path:

This next part will delete files and directories so it needs to be done carefully. If you are comfortable working from the command-line and understand  typical system administration, you can do these as they are:

```
sudo rm /_rvm
sudo rm /usr/bin/rvm-install
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rvm-prompt
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rvm-shell
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rvmsudo 

sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rvm

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/rvm/
```

If you want to be more cautious, you can open a Finder window, then do `CMD+SHFT+G` to open a "Go to the folder" dialog. Copy and paste the first *PATH* in the command-lines above, and press return. The Finder will jump to that directory. Look for that file (`_rvm`). Drag it to the trash. The system should prompt you for your sudo password. Repeat for each one of the commands. This works nicely because it lets the Finder use some of its intelligence to help protect you from my stupid mistakes. :-)

After those things are deleted your machine should be partly cleaned up. From the command-line type `echo $PATH` and see if any of those paths are listed. If so, open you `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, find where your PATH environment variable is modified, and remove that directory path.

Then, type `ls -al ~/.rvm`. If you have a `.rvm` folder in your home, then you can delete it with `rm -rf ~/.rvm`. Following that, check your .bashrc or .bash_profile for anything with rvm that does NOT point to `~/.rvm` or `/Users/your_account_name/.rvm`. Remove those, close your terminal window, then re-open it.

At this point rvm should be removed from your machine.

It's late here, and I've been sick all weekend, so we'll pick it up tomorrow with reinstalling RVM and your Rubies, or, if you feel confident, give it a try yourself. Remember, you do *NOT* have to use sudo to install RVM. It should install into your home directory without any complaints.

Also, I don't think we've established what version of the OS, or of XCode you are running. You might want to [download Apple's most recent version of XCode](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=D635F5C417E087A3B9864DAC5D25920C4E9442C9339FA9277951628F0291F620&path=%2F%2Fdevcenter%2Fmac%2Flogin.action) for your OS from their website. The version that came with Snow Leopard on the DVD has some bugs and should be upgraded ASAP. If you don't have a developer account then create one. They're free.

Comment: I updated the question. So, what I have to do now? (Thanks in advance for spending your time to help me)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. If I run the 'locate rvm | grep -v /Users' command I get 'WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.'

Comment: Uh, then run it?! It will take a little while but it is very handy. `locate` precaches, at regular intervals, the locations of files on your drive so you can quickly search for them. It's MUCH faster than using `find`.

Comment: At your orders! (hoping that everything goes well)

Comment: The first time that I run 'sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist' and nothing seems to happen. So, on the second I get the 'com.apple.locate: Already loaded' output. If I run again 'locate rvm | grep -v /Users' I get 'WARNING The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist. ...' (Sorry for my ignorance in this matter)

Comment: Ok. After that "little while" running 'locate rvm | grep -v /Users' I get a very long list. What do you want to know about that?

Comment: Remember, it said it will take a little while. The first message meant the service had been enabled. The second meant it was running. The third meant it was in the process of creating the file. It can take 30-minutes or more on a machine with a lot of files.

Comment: Read my last edit on my answer. It explains what we are looking for.

Comment: I copied all the output in a text file, but how is it possible to find "just the word "rvm" at the end of the line"?! There are at least 5000 lines containing the word 'rvm' like '/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136/version.h'. Advice on searching?

Comment: YO! I founded these where 'rvm' is at the end (or around it): '/_rvm', /usr/bin/rvm-install', '/usr/local/bin/rvm' '/usr/local/bin/rvm-prompt', '/usr/local/bin/rvm-shell', '/usr/local/bin/rvmsudo', '/usr/local/rvm/examples/rvmrc', '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm', '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm-install', '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/zsh/Completion',

Comment: I can do `sudo /usr/local/... what?! :-P

Comment: Thank you very much. I did almost all what you said and now I will try to reinstall RVM alone. See you on the web, suddenly!

Comment: I reinstalled correctly RVM and now, running the command 'rvm', I get it to work... but 'paperclip' doesn't yet: in logs I still have the problem 'Could not find paperclip-2.3.8 in any of the sources'.