# Paperclip works using the command 'rails server' but not using the basic Mac OS apache installation. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, macos, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have correctly installed the 'paperclip' gem v2.3.8 for my Ruby on Rails 3 application on my Mac OS running "Snow Leopard" v1.6.5.

What I discovered using 'paperclip' is a very strange thing: *I found that running the command 'rails server' from Terminal, my RoR3 application works great with 'paperclip', but it doesn't when I use the basic installation of apache from 'Snow Leopard'*.

In the second case, going to see logs in the 'Console Messages', I get this:

```
18/01/2011 16:50:52 org.apache.httpd[12972] [31mCould not find paperclip-2.3.8 in any of the sources[0m
```

**Why does it happen?! How to solve this issue?**

---

- I am using Ruby Version Manager (RVM)
- I am using Phusion Passenger
- I am using MacPorts
- I have installed Image-Magick through MacPorts

---

Related question: [Problem using the 'paperclip' gem and Ruby on Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719851/problem-using-the-paperclip-gem-and-ruby-on-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to specify this gem in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: No. In my Gemfile I have: gem 'paperclip', "~> 2.3"